# Adding a image view in Android

Tags: android

I have a link that takes me to an image. How would I go about accessing this link and displaying this link in Android?

Example: `http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s=GOOG&t=6m&q=l` returns a graph. How do I use this graph in Android (downloading and displaying)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a HTPPGET connection to get the connection of URL. So if you use HTTPGET, you will get an inputstream.

Once you get the inputstream, just convert that inputstream to a `Bitmap` or drawable and use as required.

Sample code is below.

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 30000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 30000);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
in = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream);
```

So you can use this bitmap as required and you need to handle all the connection exceptions.